# Верно ли согласование?

Tags: согласование

> В частности, посещение мест главных событий Крымской и Великой Отечественной войн.

Answer (score 2):

Да, здесь в принципе возможны оба варианта, но с учетом смысла однозначно — множественное, т. к. важно подчеркнуть, что войны этих две ([см. Людмила](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429151/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/429156#429156)).

К сожалению, фразу в таком виде всё равно нельзя оставлять по соображениям стилистики. Есть такое понятие — "нанизанный" или многократный родительный падеж. У вас тут три уровня — посещение мест(1) событий (2) войн (3). К сожалению, русский язык так устроен, что эта грамматически верная конструкция обычно ведет к затруднению восприятия. Это хорошо известно опытным редакторам. 
Двух уровней уже обычно достаточно, чтобы забраковать текст. А у вас — три.
Надо чего-то придумать, но советовать не буду, вам должно быть виднее.

Плюс к тому, я в общем-то согласен, что [места] "событий войн" не очень здорово звучит... Хотя "сражение" тоже неуместно. Места боев — еще более или менее.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, *"в частности, посещение мест главных **сражений** Крымской и Великой Отечественной войн"* лучше? А согласование правильное.

Answer (score 1):

Да, верно.

Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа:

1) если подчеркивается наличие нескольких предметов, например: московский и горьковский автозаводы; биологический и химический методы; академическое и массовое издания произведений классиков, широкоэкранный и обычный варианты фильма; участники гражданской и Великой Отечественной войн

http://tepka.ru/rozental_2/194.html

Answer (score 0):

"...в частности, посещение **мест главных событий Крымской и Великой Отечественной войн".**

**Здесь возможны оба варианта:** в частности, в пользу ед. числа говорит союз И и существительное "местА", которое объединяет  эти две войны. То есть речь идет не о количестве войн, не об их различии, а о памятных местах, связанных с военными действиями.

**Сравнить:**

1) Московская открытая Интернет-олимпиада по истории II-ой мировой и Великой Отечественной **войн**. [Детские развлечения (форум) (2006.01.08)]

(Здесь две группы вопросов по двум разным войнам).

2) То же относится и к имуществу, уничтоженному во время гражданской и Великой Отечественной **войны**, а также в результате стихийных бедствий. [Реабилитация жертв репрессий (2003) // «Восточно-Сибирская правда» (Иркутск), 2003.06.10]

(Здесь речь идет об имуществе, уничтоженном о время военных действий в совокупности).

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**По Розенталю,** форма мн. числа подчеркивает наличие нескольких предметов. Если исходить только из этого утверждения, то автор может подчеркивать или не подчеркивать, что и видно по примерам из Нацкорпуса: 8 примеров с  ед.числом и 14 примеров со мн.числом.

**Как они выбирались?** Может быть, наугад (кстати, мн. число является в современном языке приоритетным, если есть сомнения в выборе)? Иди возможно, у писателей есть особый слух и понимание языка, когда их не устраивает простой формализм?